# Boundedness in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If every subset of $X$ is bounded, does it mean that the space itself is bounded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you meant every that every proper subset of $X$ is bounded. In that case, take any $A, B \subsetneq X$ such that $A \cup B = X$. Hence, $X$ is bounded as a finite union of two bounded sets.

Namely $$\operatorname{diam} X = \operatorname{diam}(A\cup B) \le \operatorname{diam} A + d(A, B) + \operatorname{diam} B < +\infty$$

Comment: Technically, this argument does not work if $X$ has just one point.

Comment: Maybe we can add: for finite $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, we have $\operatorname{diam} X = \max \{d(x_i, x_j) \mid i, j = 1, \dots, n\}$ hence bounded.

Comment: @tomasz : In fact, it fails if $A$ or $B$ are empty.

Comment: @EricTowers: If $A$ or $B$ is empty and both are proper subsets of $X$, then $A\cup B\neq X$. What I meant however, is that you cannot choose such $A$ and $B$ in the first place if $X$ has just one point.

Answer (score 5):

Yes: $X$ is a subset of $X$, so it is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

Of course. After all, $X$ is a subset of itself. On the other hand, if $X$ is bounded, every subset of $X$ is bounded too.